# Shopping Cart - Left Join - would like to restrict to one row item that is closest to purchase date

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to show - All previous purchases to the customer

I have 3 tables:

```
shopping_cart
shopping_orders
audit_shopping_items
```

I want to select the price of apples closest to the apple purchase date (order date) - from - audit_shopping_items table

ISSUE : The issue is when I do a LEFT JOIN, I get 2 rows for Apples in the same order ID, code below

I just want one, the closest to product purchase date

Table : audit_shopping_items

```
+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+
| id  | item_code  |  item_name   | item_weight  | item_weight_unit  | item_quantity  | item_selling_price  | item_status  |
+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+
|   1 |  200000001 | apple        |          500 | gm                |              1 |                  10 | active       |
|   2 |  200000002 | apple_green  |          500 | gm                |              1 |                  10 | active       |
|   3 |  200000003 | avocado      |          500 | gm                |              1 |                  10 | active       |
|   4 |  200000001 | apple        |          500 | gm                |              1 |                  18 | active       |
+-----+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

My Mysql Query

```
SELECT 
  sc.item_code, 
  so.order_id, 
  si.item_name, 
  si.item_selling_price, 
FROM 
  shopping_cart as sc 
  LEFT JOIN shopping_orders AS so ON sc.order_id = so.order_id 
  LEFT JOIN audit_shopping_items AS si ON si.item_code (
    SELECT 
      pi.item_code 
    FROM 
      shopping_cart AS pi 
    WHERE 
      pi.sys_m_date <= so.sys_m_date 
      AND pi.item_code = sc.item_code 
    LIMIT 
      1
  ) 
LIMIT 
  500
```

Table : shopping_cart

```
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-
| id  |     sys_c_date       |     sys_m_date       | item_code  | item_quantity  |  order_id   | 
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-
|  1  | 2019-12-09 22:05:05  | 2019-12-09 22:05:15  | 200000001  |             2  | 1869460212  | 
|  2  | 2019-12-09 22:05:08  | 2019-12-09 22:05:15  | 200000003  |             2  | 1869460212  | 
|  3  | 2019-12-09 22:06:16  | 2019-12-09 22:06:24  | 200000001  |             4  | 2891252193  | 
|  4  | 2019-12-09 22:06:18  | 2019-12-09 22:06:24  | 200000004  |             2  | 2891252193  | 
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-
```

Table : shopping_orders

```
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+
| id  |     sys_c_date       |     sys_m_date       |  order_id   | order_amount  |   order_owner    | order_status   | order_method |
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+
|  1  | 2019-12-09 22:05:15  | 2019-12-09 22:05:15  | 1869460212  |           40  | abc@example.com  | created        | cod          |
|  2  | 2019-12-09 22:06:24  | 2019-12-09 22:06:24  | 2891252193  |           92  | abc@example.com  | created        | cod          |
+-----+----------------------+----------------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Why are you doing an OUTER JOIN of the `audit_shopping_items` table? What would it mean if there were no pricing information for a purchase? Is such a thing really possible? Likewise, why are you doing  an OUTER JOIN with the `shopping_orders` table? If you were missing a `shopping_order`, for example, `pi.sys_m_date <= so.sys_m_date` could not be true.

Comment: There seems to be lots of stuff here that's not actually relevant tp the problem. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry , I have edited the information, please have a look when you get a chance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOINING audit_shopping_items AS si ON -- si.id -- instead of -- si.item_code -- to pi-id resolved the issue

```
            SELECT 
              sc.item_code, 
              so.order_id, 
              si.item_name, 
              si.item_selling_price, 
            FROM 
              shopping_cart as sc 
              LEFT JOIN shopping_orders AS so ON sc.order_id = so.order_id 
              LEFT JOIN audit_shopping_items AS si ON si.id (
                SELECT 
                  pi.id 
                FROM 
                  shopping_cart AS pi 
                WHERE 
                  pi.sys_m_date <= so.sys_m_date 
                  AND pi.item_code = sc.item_code 
                LIMIT 
                  1
              ) 
            LIMIT 
              500
```